# Show head of the dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to view first 20 rows of the dataframe where x > 2, additionally rows should be sorted from the highest to lowest number based on x column. See example

```
df

  x y z
a 3 1 0
b 5 2 2
c 1 0 2
```

result

```
  x y z
b 5 1 0
a 3 2 2
```

Comment: This is a very basic question. What did you try and where did you fail?

Comment: Try `head(dat[dat$x > 2, ][order(dat[dat$x > 2, ]$x), ], 20)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R, you can `subset` and `order`

```
temp <- head(subset(df, x > 2), 20)
temp[order(-temp$x), ]

#  x y z
#b 5 2 2
#a 3 1 0
```

Comment: Here is a one-liner `head(subset(df[order(df$x, decreasing = TRUE),], x > 2), 20)`

Answer (score 2):

I hope the following logic using the library `dplyr` and the dataset `iris`can help you out:

```
library(dplyr)
data(iris)

iris%>% filter(Species =="virginica")%>%
        arrange(desc(Petal.Length))%>%
        head(20)

# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
# 1           7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 virginica
# 2           7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica
# 3           7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0 virginica
# 4           7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
# 5           7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0 virginica
# 6           7.3         2.9          6.3         1.8 virginica
# 7           7.2         3.6          6.1         2.5 virginica
# 8           7.4         2.8          6.1         1.9 virginica
# 9           7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3 virginica
# 10          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5 virginica
# 11          7.2         3.2          6.0         1.8 virginica
# 12          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1 virginica
# 13          6.8         3.2          5.9         2.3 virginica
# 14          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2 virginica
# 15          6.7         2.5          5.8         1.8 virginica
# 16          7.2         3.0          5.8         1.6 virginica
# 17          6.9         3.2          5.7         2.3 virginica
# 18          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.1 virginica
# 19          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5 virginica
# 20          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8 virginica
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`

```
df %>%
filter(x>2) %>%
arrange(desc(x)) %>%
head(20)
```

Comment: I am struggling with dplyr, would you be able to recommend alternative solution?